# Open source projects using asp.net mvc + silverlight

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, open-source

Are there any open source projects using both asp.net mvc and silverlight together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i couldn't find an open source project (doesn't mean they don't exist) but here is some good resources about mvc with silverlight [here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/02/09/silverlight-as-a-view-in-aspnet-mvc.aspx) and [here](http://stephenwalther.com/Blog/archive/2008/08/01/asp-net-mvc-application-building-1-family-video-website-upload-the-videos.aspx)

Comment: There aren't any widely known open source projects using these 2 together.

Answer (score 1):

I guess one of the largest open source projects that are using asp.net MVC and silverlight would be the mono project. They have gone and recreated asp.net mvc and silverlight as [mono mvc](http://www.mono-project.com/news/archive/2009/Jul-06.html)and [moonlight](http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight), though I would guess that you're looking for 'applications' or 'sites' that use these two technologies.

Two large projects that do use asp.net MVC as expected are [Micorosoft's Orchard CMS](http://orchard.codeplex.com/) and [Rob Conery's Kona Project](http://github.com/robconery/Kona). Althought I do not think that these have silverlight included with them. I think that both are pure MVC applications.

Good luck in your search, and hope this helped some.